# Find total page numbers entered in php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I made a textbox labeled as "**Page Numbers**".

The user may enter the page numbers in any sequence like `1, 3, 6`.

I want to handle that if user entered `1, 4, 2, 6-8, 10`. Then I should know that the user selected page number `1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10`.

That means the user can also enter the range as well as comma separated numbers like we give the page numbers while printing documents.

The order number of pages can also be changed. For e.g. `5, 6, 4-8, 1`. The numbers can be repeated but I need only the unique page numbers.

How I can do it in PHP? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the plan of attack:

1. Split the string by comma and iterate through the values
2. For each value validate that it's either a number or two numbers separated by a hyphen
3. If it's a single number, add it to your page number set
4. If it's a range then split the string by hyphen
5. Determine which number is the smaller one and for loop from the smaller one to the larger one, each time adding the number to the set
6. Sort the set.

I'd make the set an assoc array and when I add a number to it I'd set it as the key.  E.g.

```
$pageNumbers[$number] = true;
```

Here's the code:

```
$pageNumberStr = $_REQUEST['pageNumberStr'];

$components = explode(",", $pageNumberStr);

$pageNumbers = array();

foreach ($components as $component) {
   $component = trim($component);
   if (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $component)) {
      $pageNumbers[$component] = true;
   } else if (preg_match('/^(\d+)-(\d+)$/', $component, $matches)) {
      $first = min($matches[1], $matches[2]);
      $last = max($matches[1], $matches[2]);

      for ($i = $first; $i <= $last; $i++) {
         $pageNumbers[$i] = true;
      }
   }
}

$pageNumbers = array_keys($pageNumbers);
sort($pageNumbers);
```

Comment: Read up on regexes today and I have a minor suggestion - I'd consider changing all `*` into `+` seeing as there needs to be at least one number in each place for it to work.  `*` will accept an empty string as a pattern match.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think my answer is as nice as emuranos, but here's what I whipped up since I don't know how to use regular expressions (this also requires them to enter page ranges as min-max instead of max-min, and to enter all numbers with a ", " between them):

```
$answer = array();
$text = "1, 4, 2, 6-8, 10, 2-4, 9, 10";
$nums = explode(", ", $text);

foreach ($nums as $value)
{
    if (strpos($value, "-") == false)
        if (!in_array($value, $answer)) array_push($answer, $value);
    else
    {
        $newVal = split("-", $value);
        for ($i = $newVal[0]; $i <= $newVal[1]; $i++)
            if (!in_array($i, $answer)) array_push($answer, $i);
    }
}

sort($answer);
```

Comment: Will it also manage the spaces means between hyphen or comma etc.?

Comment: contrary to the response of emurano, your solution assumes that the users enter only correct values. But if a user enter for instance "1,2, qwe, 3--4, 5", your code would fail. Learning regular expressions may seem difficult at first glance, but it is worth it as it is very powerful.

Comment: Ahh yes I should have used in_array instead of using an assoc array!

Comment: @nicO but they look so scary!  I'll make learning basic ones my task for today.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode your textbox value and sort that array then find out values from that array with range and push that values in array if not exist and sort it again. I think this would done it.

Answer (score 0):

Something a bit more compact:

```
<?php
function parsePages($values) {
    foreach(explode(',', $values) as $val) {
        $val = trim($val);
        if (ctype_digit($val)) {
            $pages[] = $val;
        } elseif (preg_match('/^(\d+)-(\d+)$/', $val, $matches)) {
            $pages = array_merge($pages, range($matches[1], $matches[2]));
        }
    }
    return array_unique($pages);
}
```

`\d+` matches one or more. `\d*` matches 0 or more, so it would match just a `-` string.